# Include a pipe | as content in table in Git Readme.md file

Tags: git, github, gitlab, markdown, readme

I'm using Gitlab and trying to include a pipe | sign as content within the table in the README.md file. I followed [the example showed here](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/) but the output is not the expected one. Any other ways to do it?

README contents

```
| Name     | Character |
| ---      | ---       |
| Backtick | `         |
| Pipe     | \|        |
```

My Output

[image: README Table with pipe]

Expected Output

[image: README Table with pipe expected]

Also, how can I use pipe in a codeblock like this:

```
| Name         | Command   |
| ---          | ---       |
| Show Files   | `ls`      |
| Grep History | `history | grep pip`|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the html code without the space between & and #

```
& #124;


| Name     | Character |
| ---      | ---       |
| Backtick | `         |
| Pipe     | &#124;    |
```

Your answer to the second part per our comments would be:

```
| Grep History | <code>history &#124; grep pip<\code>|
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me how can I do it inside a code block like $ history | grep pip? I tried the html code inside the code block but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AbuShoeb Can you provide an example of what you want? You can wrap html codes in the <code></code> tags.

Comment: Which version are you on? looks like \| should work in your grep

Comment: just added, please see the bottom part of the question.

Comment: $history | grep \|    is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, just wanted to have the pipe inside the code block, see the example at the end.

Comment: | Grep History | <code>history &#124; grep pip<\code>|  @AbuShoeb

Comment: Best of luck in your coding!